# Funny Behavior in SQL Case Statement, Certain case always gets hit

Tags: sql, case-statement

I'm running the following SQL but the 0 case seems to always get hit:

```
 select 
ccy.numberofdecimals,
ABS(round(ts.TRADECCY1AMOUNT, 2)),

CASE 
WHEN CCY.NUMBEROFDECIMALS = 0 THEN
CONVERT(Numeric(38,0), ABS(round(TS.TRADECCY1AMOUNT, 0)))
WHEN CCY.NUMBEROFDECIMALS = 2 THEN
CONVERT(Numeric(38,2), ABS(round(TS.TRADECCY1AMOUNT, 2)))
WHEN CCY.NUMBEROFDECIMALS = 3 THEN
CONVERT(Numeric(38,3), ABS(round(TS.TRADECCY1AMOUNT, 3)))
END as 'Transaction Amount',


FROM
blah blah blah
```

Yet my result set is always:

[image]

When I remove the 0 number of decimal case, it produces the correct result. Anyone have any ideas as to why this case statement always evaluates the 0 case?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have a column with different dataypes, its either `Numeric(38,0)`, `Numeric(38,2)` or `Numeric(38,3)`, so it assigns the first datatype to all rows on your column

Comment: @Lamak - You can cast one branch to `sql_variant` dataype though which will then give the desired results. Although this looks like something that the presentation layer should deal with.

Comment: @MartinSmith - You are right, though in my mind `sql_variant` is still a single datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I think missing your else statement and having different data types will make it all confused.  Here's a good debugging technique that you should learn.  Simplify your code to the point where it's completely basic.  Then start adding in your logic.  You'll find where you're making a mistake very fast.  In your case, start with this:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN t.a = 0 THEN 1
    WHEN t.a = 2 THEN 2
    WHEN t.a = 3 THEN 3
END as c
FROM (  select 1 as a
        union
        select 2 as a
        union
        select 3 as a
     ) t
```

and change your THEN clauses one by one.  Obviously the CASE statement works, so it must be something you're doing.